# XOR Neural Network completely from scratch (No numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm coding a neural network purely from scratch (absolutely no numpy or anything for calculations). I completed this easily using Numpy and matrix multiplication, but for some reason purely from scratch this doesn't work. I'm getting poor results like so:

```
Predictions: 
[array([[0.6043366]]), array([[0.69588648]]), array([[0.4990016]]), array([[0.00369652]])]
```

```
X = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
Y = [0,1,1,0]

epochs = 100000

W1 = np.random.randn(1,1)
W2 = np.random.randn(1,1)
W3 = np.random.randn(1,1)
W4 = np.random.randn(1,1)
W5 = np.random.randn(1,1)
W6 = np.random.randn(1,1)

h1_bias = 0
h2_bias = 0
output_bias = 0

def sigmoid(inputs):
    return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-inputs))

lr = 0.01
for i in range(epochs):
    preds = []
    for idx, x in enumerate(X):
        label = Y[idx]
        i1 = x[0]
        i2 = x[1]
        
        
        h1 = W1*i1 + W2*i2 + h1_bias
        
        h2 = W3*i1 + W4*i2 + h2_bias
        
        h1 = sigmoid(h1)
        h2 = sigmoid(h2)
        
        output = W5*h1 + W6*h2 + output_bias
        output = sigmoid(output)
        
        preds.append(output)
        
        loss_gradient = -1*((label / output) - (1-label) / (1-output))
        
        output_activation_grad = loss_gradient * output * (1 - output)

        update_output_bias = output_activation_grad
        update_W5 = output_activation_grad * h1
        update_W6 = output_activation_grad * h2
        
        h1_grad = output_activation_grad * W5
        h2_grad = output_activation_grad * W6
        
        h1_activation_grad = h1_grad * h1 * (1 - h1)
        h2_activation_grad = h2_grad * h2 * (1 - h2)

        update_h1_bias = h1_activation_grad
        update_h2_bias = h2_activation_grad
        update_W1 = h1_activation_grad * i1
        update_W2 = h1_activation_grad * i2
        update_W3 = h2_activation_grad * i1
        update_W4 = h2_activation_grad * i2
        
        W1 -= lr*update_W1
        W2 -= lr*update_W2
        W3 -= lr*update_W3
        W4 -= lr*update_W4
        W5 -= lr*update_W5
        W6 -= lr*update_W6
        output_bias -= lr*update_output_bias
        h1_bias -= lr*update_h1_bias
        h2_bias -= lr*update_h2_bias

        
print("Predictions: {}".format(preds))
```

Is my derivation purely from scratch correct? Why is it not converging anymore?

Comment: Try checking the gradient calculation against divided differences. That is, approximate each derror/dweight by a finite approximation, (delta error)/(delta weight). Just add a small (delta weight) to each weight, one at a time, and see how the error changes. If (delta weight) is small, the vector of divided differences should be close to your computed gradient.

Comment: @RobertDodier Can you expand on that? I'm a bit confused by what you mean.

Comment: Well, you can approximate the derivative of a (well-behaved) continuous function, I'll call it f, as just (f(x + (delta x)) - f(x))/(delta x), where (delta x) is a small number. For a gradient, you just do that once for each input variable x. I think a web search for "gradient approximation divided differences" will turn up some resources, probably even "neural network gradient approximation divided differences".

Comment: @RobertDodier I appreciate the response, but I think my issue revolves more around the implementation and I can't directly see the error.

Comment: Right, the point of comparing the gradient is to see, okay, the derivatives for the weights are right but the derivatives for the biases are wrong. Or the weights for the input-to-hidden are right but the ones for the hidden-to-output are wrong. Or everything's off by a factor of minus 2. I don't know what you'll find, but it's a good way to find it.

Comment: I guess I'm confused since I thought XOR could be solved relatively easily with a 2-layer NN. For example from this NN (which is what I coded above) https://victorzhou.com/77ed172fdef54ca1ffcfb0bba27ba334/network.svg. My understanding was that with this setup it should be trivial to learn. This is why I think my gradient computation or programmatic steps are incorrect as I've completed this XOR problem with a similar NN, but utilizing Numpy and matrix multiplication. I'm simply seeing oscillating error, which implies a LR too large I thought, but adjusting has no effect.

Comment: Debugging neural network code can be tricky since there are several moving parts and the error could be in any of them. Comparing the gradient to an approximation is a good way to either verify there's a problem there or rule it out. I agree that XOR is simple conceptually, but all the pieces have to work. I don't know in which part of your code the error is, I'm just suggesting something you can do to try to find it.