# MATLAB Backpropagation Algorithm not functioning as expected

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, math, backpropagation

I am attempting to write a Multi-Layer Perceptron Network inside MATLAB to help me better understand the calculus required for backpropagation.

The aim is so provide the network with XOR data (where upper-right and lower-left quadrant data is class 1 and the remaining quadrants class 0), train the network on this data, and then test it on new data.

My problem is that my loss curve looks very very strange:

[image: Loss curve]

It appears to bounce between very low error very high error and converge in the middle to a pretty poor error.

I was wondering if someone could check that I have correctly implemented the chain rule in MATLAB syntax.

The MLP network is structured as follows: Input-layer has 2 neurons, 1 hidden-layer with 2 neurons, and 1 output neuron.

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
%Create XOR Dataset

x1pos = rand(500,1);
x1neg = -rand(500,1);
x1 = [x1pos; x1neg];
p = randperm(length(x1));
x1 = x1(p);
x2pos = rand(500,1);
x2neg = -rand(500,1);
x2 = [x1pos; x1neg];
p = randperm(length(x2));
x2 = x2(p);

Data = [x1 x2];
TrainingData = Data(1:800,:);
TestData = Data(801:length(Data),:);

T = gt((Data(:,1).*Data(:,2)),0); %Create class label for data and assign to matrix T

%Neural Net

%Training

W1 = rand(2,2); %Initialize random weights
W2 = rand(1,2); %Initialize random weights

B1 = rand(2,1); %Initialize random biases
B2 = rand(1,1); %Initialize random biases

n = 0.05; %Set Learning Rate


    for i = 1:800
        %Fwd Pass
    
        x1 = Data(i,1);
        x2 = Data(i,2);
        X = [x1; x2];
        A1 = W1*X + B1;
        H1 = sigmoid(A1);
        A2 = W2*H1 + B2;
        Y = sigmoid(A2);
    
        %Loss
        
        Loss = (Y-T(i))*(Y-T(i));
    
        scatter(i, Loss)
        hold on;
    
        %Backpropagation
    
        dEdY = 2*(Y-T(i)); %The partial derivative of the loss with respect to the output
        dYdA2 = Y*(1-Y); %The partial derivative of the output with respect to the hidden layer output
        dA2dH1 = W2.'; %The partial derivative of the hidden layer output with respect to the first layer activations
        dH1dA1 = H1.*(1-H1); %The partial derivative of the first layer activations with respect to the first layer output
        
        %Chain Rule
        
        dEdW2 = dEdY.*dYdA2.*W2.';
        dEdW1 = dEdY.*dYdA2.*dA2dH1.*dH1dA1.*W1.';
        dEdB2 = dEdY.*dYdA2;
        dEdB1 = dEdY.*dYdA2.*dA2dH1.*dH1dA1;
    
        %Update Weights
    
        W2 = (W2.' - n.*dEdW2).';
        W1 = (W1.' - n.*dEdW1).';
    
        %Update Biases
    
        B2 = B2 - n.*dEdB2;
        B1 = B1 - n.*dEdB1;
    
        %Next training loop
    end

%Testing

for i = 801:1000
    x1 = Data(i,1);
    x2 = Data(i,2);
    X = [x1; x2];
    A1 = W1*X + B1;
    H1 = sigmoid(A1);
    A2 = W2*H1 + B2;
    Y = sigmoid(A2);
end

function o = sigmoid(input)
    o = [];
    for i = 1:length(input)
        o = [o; 1/(1+exp(-input(i)))];
    end
end
```

Comment: Harry, looks like you've made a good start, but it's going to be pretty hard for others to help without actually redoing the whole thing themselves, so I think you'll need to try to get to the bottom of it. BP is based on gradients, so my main advice is to check the gradient calculation, by computing the gradient via finite differences, and compare that to your hopefully-exact gradient. I made some comments on other question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521224/xor-neural-network-completely-from-scratch-no-numpy

Comment: Also, you might want to be more explicit about what you mean that the "loss curve looks very very strange".

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you very much for your reply. I have edited my post based on your comments, hopefully that makes my problem with the loss curve a bit clearer! I will have a look at your comments the post you linked :)